# Delphi 10.4 and TRESTRequest causing unknown error Webbroker ISAPI DLL

Tags: delphi

We have an issue with this on our Xero API integration. The RestRequest.Execute is causing us an error for no reason. But when we are running it as a stand-alone application (localhost exe) it is working perfectly. But converting it to a Webbroker ISAPI DLL and running on our domain thru IIS, we cannot get passed the first RESTRequest.Execute line. Currently using Delphi 10.4 & REST Components as a Webbroker with ISAPI.

```
function TXero2.GetAccessToken(Authorization, sAuthCode, ReDirectURI: AnsiString): AnsiString;
begin
 TRY

  ResetRESTComponentsToDefaults;
  RESTClient.UserAgent := XeroUserAgent;
  RESTRequest.Client := RESTClient;

  RESTClient.BaseURL := XeroAPIIdentityURL;
  RESTClient.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  RESTClient.Params.AddItem('Authorization', Authorization, TRESTRequestParameterkind.pkHTTPHEADER, [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode]);
  RESTRequest.Resource := 'connect/token';

  RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('grant_type', 'authorization_code', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY);
  RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('code', sAuthCode, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY);
  RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('redirect_uri', ReDirectURI, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY);

  RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  RESTRequest.Execute;﻿ //error occurs here

   result := Restresponse.Content;

 EXCEPT
      on e: Exception do
         Codesite.Send(ClassName + '.GetAccessToken: ' + e.Message);
   END;
end;
```

This is really just a straight forward command and works fine when stand-alone. Anyone experiencing the same issue?

Comment: Please post the content of `e.Message`.

Comment: It's actually an Access Violation.  Access violation at address 00000000057D02F2 in module 'testapi.dll'. Read of address 0000000000000000

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue thru this post here at Embarcadero: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31067